# How to join two variables to log another variable

Tags: javascript

I have two variables that I need to join and then print the value of a different variable which has the name of the variables I just joined.

I have:

```
var NoQ = "1234, 4321, 6789"

var NoQ1 = "Number: " + NoQ.slice(0,4);
var NoQ2 = "Number: " + NoQ.slice(5,9);

var i = 1 //i is in a for loop so i++

console.log(NoQ+i)  
//prints 1234, 4321, 67891
```

I want `NoQ` and `i` to join to technically become `NoQ1` before logging.

Expected output: `Number: 1234`

How do I achieve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: But `NoQ` is `"1234, 4321, 6789"`, so shouldn't the output be: `"number: 1234, 4321, 6789"` ?

Comment: No, because I want it to print `NoQ1` but joined `NoQ` and `i`.

Comment: Can you please post the full output you're expecting? It's unclear what you're asking. Do you want to split based on `,`?

Comment: Can you try and rewrite this question, it's not making much sense at the moment e.g. `to join to technically become` what do you mean `technically`?

Comment: Are you aware `console.log` can take several parameters which will be printed in row ?  `console.log('one', 'two', 'three', 'four') // one two three four`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/) for ordered items and return the value with an index.

The wanted type is not possible to get a variable in a variable for accessing a value.

```js
var noQ = "1234, 4321, 6789",
    noQs = noQ.split(/,\s*/g).map(s => `Number: ${s}`);

console.log(noQs[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

var NoQ = "1234, 4321, 6789";

```
var i = 1;

console.log('Number: ' + NoQ.split(', ')[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access global variables on `window` so you can use array access syntax to access those variables with a string value:

```js
var NoQ = "1234, 4321, 6789"

var NoQ1 = "Number: " + NoQ.slice(0,4);
var NoQ2 = "Number: " + NoQ.slice(5,9);

var i = 1 //i is in a for loop so i++

for (let i = 1; i <= 2; ++i)
  console.log(window['NoQ' + i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a template string to build your output string and [`string.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with a regex to split your input string on the commas and get rid of the extra space:

```js
const NoQ = "1234, 4321, 6789"

const NoQi = i => `Number: ${NoQ.split(/,\s*/)[i - 1]}`

console.log(NoQi(1))
console.log(NoQi(2))
console.log(NoQi(3))
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `console.log(window['NoQ'+i])`
NOT the best solution, but it is the closest to what you are trying to do.